# How I can upload video on Youtube from my android application?

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api

I am confused in creating account on google for it? Please anyone tell me whole procedure for uploading video on youtube in easily steps . & then how to get that URl from youtube in my android application?

Comment: what you are asking is completely vague .... what you have tried so far and where you stucked and confused about what ?? ... you need to explain these stuffs first ..

Answer (score 1):

See this
http://code.google.com/p/ytd-android/

Answer (score 0):

You may use Youtube API do upload video, check here https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_feeds#User_Uploaded_Videos

Answer (score 0):

The sample code for the YouTube Direct Android application that Albin linked to is the canonical example right now.

As soon as [v3 of the Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) is released, though, that will be the preferred way of handling uploads from a native Android application, since the Java Google APIs client library will work with both Android and v3 (the current Java GData client library works with v2, but not Android).

(To answer the next question, no, I can't share a release date for v3 of the API.)